# (Vim) How to use TAB for indentation in all file types?

Tags: vim, vimrc, indentation

I'm using only *TAB* for indent, so I configure Vim for using only them:

```
set autoindent
set noexpandtab
set tabstop=4
set shiftwidth=4
```

But some files (`.py`) still using *spaces*. I've search for it and found:

```
filetype plugin indent on
```

But this has not help, and I've try:

```
au FileType python setlocal noexpandtab
```

But this has help only for python. So how to apply `noexpandtab` for **all** file types?

Comment: Actually, as it turns out, Python is a bit of an exception. You are meant to [only use spaces (_not_ tabs) for Python programming](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#tabs-or-spaces).

Comment: I'm curious why this is downvoted so much. The question is clear and concise. And it shows the OP has put forth effort in solving it. Just because you don't agree with the practice doesn't make the question bad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some vim syntaxes set certain settings when the file is opened. As you've found, you can get around this by using an `autocmd` to set the setting after the syntax has finished.
To get the `autocmd` to apply on all file types, use a `*`. For example:

```
autocmd FileType * set noexpandtab
```